# Generic type with TypeORM repositories

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typescript-generics

I am trying to make a abstract base service that will be generic type, that type extends from abstract class `BaseModel` with one property `slug`.

When i try to do a repository find by the slug attribute I get a typescript error.

```
this.repository.findOneOrFail({ slug: slug });
```

Typescript error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(id?: string | number | Date | ObjectID | undefined, options?: FindOneOptions<Entity> | undefined): Promise<Entity>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ slug: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date | ObjectID | undefined'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'slug' does not exist in type 'Date | ObjectID'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(options?: FindOneOptions<Entity> | undefined): Promise<Entity>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ slug: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOneOptions<Entity>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'slug' does not exist in type 'FindOneOptions<Entity>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(conditions?: FindConditions<Entity> | undefined, options?: FindOneOptions<Entity> | undefined): Promise<Entity>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ slug: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindConditions<Entity>'.
```

**Entities**:

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

export abstract class BaseModel {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  slug: string;
}

@Entity()
export class Link extends BaseModel {
  @Column()
  url: string;
}
```

**BaseService**

```
export abstract class BaseService<Entity extends BaseModel> {
  constructor(protected readonly repository: Repository<Entity>) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<Entity[]> {
    return this.repository.find();
  }

  async findBySlug(slug: string): Promise<Entity> {
    return this.repository.findOneOrFail({ slug: slug });
  }

  async deleteById(id: number): Promise<any> {
    return this.repository.delete(id);
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#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-oQEqD0o0Ynw4dVRKjmu1eqwhswxpp2n1NZMzdMJekQ3uQA)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I have found to make it work was:

```
  async findBySlug(slug: string): Promise<Entity> {
    return this.repository.findOneOrFail({ slug: slug } as any);
  }
```

I don't know if it's the best way, but it works!

Comment: Be careful with that; it may get TypeScript to pass on your code, but you increase your chances of runtime bugs in your app code.